# Express : How to Add Middleware Exclusively to a Large List of Routes in a Router Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to modularize all my routes by stacking router objects.

My problem with stacking routers(initializing with index.js and tacking on router objects with
`router.use`) is when you want to add a middleware call to every route in a specific router(exclusively) but if the list of routes is large - trying to put the middleware in front of the routes to avoid having to insert it into every route.

For Example: Applying `middleware.doSomething` to all the routes.

```
other.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var middleware = require("./middleware");


router.use(middleware.doSomething);

router.get('/routeC', function(req, res){
    ... 
});

router.get('/routeD', function(req, res){
    ... 
});

router.get('/routeE', function(req, res){
    ... 
});

exports.module = router;
```

Problem

A middleware handler of one router, like `middleware.doSomething` can unexpectedly be called as express goes through the process of matching paths from general to specific (eg. "/" then "/routeA" then "/routeA/:paramA").

For Example: When trying to handle "/routeA" the router specific middleware `router.use(middleware.doSomething);` will be called unexpectedly.

Route Structure

```
/routes
 -index.js
 -other.js
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.use(require(./other));

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    ... 
});

router.get('/routeA', function(req, res){
    ... 
});

router.get('/routeB', function(req, res){
    ... 
});

exports.module = router;
```

**server.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes');
app.use(routes);
```

Question:

How could we make `router.use(middleware.doSomething);` private to it's router object(without adding it to every individual route), or avoid this issue by design/pattern that scales nicely as we stack additional routers? (I'm open to any ideas using prefixes, I was just avoiding them because I didn't want to prefix the ajax calls too).

Comment: Is there some part of your code that is not working as you want? middleware.doSomething is only called when you hit a route in other.js now.

Comment: ```middleware.doSomething``` will be hit if you try to route to "/routeA" for example.

Comment: Not with your code on my machine.

Comment: What? Weird! What version of node/express you using? By design, should  middlewar.doSomething  be exclusive to its router object other.js?

Comment: node@v5.4.1, express@4.13.4. Yes. When you add middleware to a router it's exclusive for that. For general middleware you typically add it on the express object with `app.use`

Comment: "unexpectedly" how? Middlewares and routes are invoked in the order you defined them, as expected. What's causing the unexpected behavior?

Comment: Also to "make it private" you can do `app.use('/routeA', middleware.dosomething)` to make that middleware only invoke if the path matches, is this what you wanted?

Comment: @laggingreflex yea I want to keep the middleware private to the router in order to logically split routes into different files even though they might share the same prefix.

Answer (score 0):

am sure you can, not exactly by design only, also, with your code pattern as well, here is how:

lets assume you have this main.js

```
var app = require('express')();

// add universal middle ware
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    console.log("universal");
    next();
    });
// lets assume you have 2 groups of routes, then you pass your express to them.
require('./route01.js')(app);
require('./route02.js')(app);

app.listen(4321);
```

let assume also this is a route01 group file file

```
module.exports = function(app)
{
    // universal middleware for routes1
    app.use('/route01',function(req, res, next){
        console.log("universal middleware for routes1")
        next();
        });

    app.get('/route01/option01',function(req,res,next){
        console.log("specific middleware for route 1 option 1");
        next();
        },function(req,res){res.send("OK")});

    app.get('/route01/option02',function(req,res,next){
        console.log("specific middleware for route 1 option 2");
        next();
        },function(req,res){res.send("OK")});
}
```

and this is the route02 group file file

```
module.exports = function(app)
{
    // universal middleware for routes2
    app.use('/route02',function(req, res, next){
        console.log("universal middleware for routes2")
        next();
        });
    // pass specific middle ware for the routes
    app.get('/route02/option01',function(req,res,next){
        console.log("specific middleware for route 2 option 1");
        next();
        },function(req,res){res.send("OK")});

    app.get('/route02/option02',function(req,res,next){
        console.log("specific middleware for route 2 option 2");
        next();
        },function(req,res){res.send("OK")});
}
```

for example, you hit http://127.0.0.1:4321/route01/option02, the output will be

> universal
>
> universal middleware for routes1
>
> specific middleware for route 1 option 2

and if hit http://127.0.0.1:4321/route02/option01 for example you get

> universal
>
> universal middleware for routes2
>
> specific middleware for route 2 option 1

Comment: The solution you've provided forces you to use a prefix for the routes.

Comment: @jared_flack have you read this statement in the question "I'm open to any ideas using prefixes" ? or have you even read the question at all :)

Comment: That escalated quickly. @abdullah-shahin, you're right, I didn't read that part of OP's question.